# How do I resume from pm-suspend?

Tags: debian

I can't believe I have to ask this but an hour of searching leaves me with no answer.  I use 'hibernate' all the time and it works fine, but I had thought to try 'suspend' instead.  'pm-suspend' shuts the computer down alright but how the heck do I get it fired up again?  This is with Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I am understanding correctly, what you need to do is through hardware, press the power button of the computer, laptop or tablet, so that it resumes, the resume will be successful if you are not using a LIVE CD, since some LIVE CD can give resume problems, since everything is stored in ram, if it is not the case, everything will work correctly, through software it would probably be impossible unless the bios allowed such an option in the hardware, since when hibernating the data stops and the course of energy is stopped in certain areas of the computer, to guarantee absolutely minimal or null consumption, but in the case of suspending the computer, the energy remains active in the ram and in other areas, thus allowing that can be resumed through software more easily without having to go to hardware.

I hope this will help...

Comment: Damn.  I tried everything *but* the power button :(  ... and voila!  the power button does it :)  thanks Matty.